# Mensagem de erro ao gerar relatório

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Estou fazendo um relatório e está dando uma mensagem de erro que não estou conseguindo encontrar solução.

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código botão Gerar

```
   private void btnGerarRelatorio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dsum = new DataSet();
        DataTable oTable = new DataTable();

        String strReportPath = "";
        try
        {
            strReportPath = @"Report4.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = strReportPath;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DENILSON-PC;Initial Catalog=dbSistEstoqueEmp;Integrated Security=True");

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbEntradaEstoque WHERE cod_peca = @codPeca AND data_ent BETWEEN @dataEnt AND @dataEnt1";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("codPeca", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodPeca.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("dataEnt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(maskDataInicial.Text).Date;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("dataEnt1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(maskDataFinal.Text).Date;

            SqlDataReader oDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            oTable.Load(oDataReader);
            ReportDataSource myReportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("dbEntSaidaPeca", oTable);
            reportViewer1.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources[0] = myReportDataSource;
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome do `Dataset` passado como argumento do `ReportDataSource` deve ser o mesmo do configurado no arquivo RDLC do report. Então a criação do ReportDataSource deveria ser:

```
 ReportDataSource myReportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", oTable);
```

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou muito, deixa eu te perguntar para eu pegar 2 tabelas tbEntradaPeca e tbSaidaPeca como eu faria isso no relatório ? escolheria uma peça cod 1 data inicial e data final e me mostrava todas as entradas e saida no relatorio desta peça, se puder me ajudar eu agradeço preciso entregar isso dia 12 na faculdade.